I get the error message unexpected Token "-Install"
I have an new Windows 11 System and I try to install a script
under Windows Powershell ISE as follows
PS C:\Windows\System32> 
"\0_Common\Hintergrund\Lockscreen Programm\Collect-Lockscreens11.ps1" -Install

which was fine under Windows 10
After writing in Windows (11) Powershell ISE the same command
"\0_Common\Hintergrund\Lockscreen Programm\Collect-Lockscreens11.ps1" -Install

I get the error message
In Zeile:1 Zeichen:73
+ ... n\Hintergrund\Lockscreen Programm\Collect-Lockscreens11.ps1" -Install
+                                                                  ~~~~~~~~
Unerwartetes Token "-Install" in Ausdruck oder Anweisung.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken

unexpected Token "-Install" in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken

What do I wrong? Thank you very much for helping

In short: Targeting an executable (including .ps1 files and batch files) by a name or path that is quoted or contains variable references must - for syntactic reasons - be invoked with &, the call operator; see the linked duplicate for details.

As an aside: The PowerShell ISE is no longer actively developed and there are reasons not to use it (bottom section), notably not being able to run PowerShell (Core) 7. The actively developed, cross-platform editor that offers the best PowerShell development experience is Visual Studio Code with its PowerShell extension.

Also: PowerShell's syntax has always worked that way, and the behavior is unrelated to the OS version, so your command wouldn't have worked in Windows 10 either.

You forgot to prefix the command you want to invoke with the invocation operator &:
PS C:\Windows\System32> & "\0_Common\Hintergrund\Lockscreen Programm\Collect-Lockscreens11.ps1" -Install
                        ^ you need this guy 

